# Set Xamarin.Forms binding CommandParameter in code behind

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, code-behind

I'm trying to set binding on a `TapGestureRecognizer` in code and I can't figure out the right way to do it. The working xaml looks something like this...

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding LaunchLocationDetailsCommand}" 
                              CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
    </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
</Grid>
```

And in C#, it looks something like this...

```
var gridTap = new TapGestureRecognizer();

gridTap.SetBinding(TapGestureRecognizer.CommandProperty, 
                   new Binding("LaunchLocationDetailsCommand"));

gridTap.SetBinding(TapGestureRecognizer.CommandParameterProperty, 
                   new Binding(/* here's where I'm confused */));

var grid = new Grid();
grid.GestureRecognizers.Add(gridTap);
```

My confusion comes in on the binding of `CommandParameterProperty`. In xaml, this simply `{Binding}` with no other parameter. How is this done in code? Passing in `new Binding()` or `this.BindingContext` don't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `CommandProperty` binding is the same as you was doing.

As you are not passing in a path to some property to use, your `CommandParameterProperty` can't just create an empty `Binding` as it will throw an exception.

To get around this you need to specify the `Source` property as Adam has pointed out.

Note, however if the `BindingContext` you are trying to assign **is** `Null`, which I suspect it is in your case, this will **still** throw an exception.

The `Grid` in the example below has the `BindingContext` set to the view model (`objGrid.BindingContext = objMyView2`).

We are then creating a new binding for our command parameter, with the `Source` pointing back to our view model (`Source = objGrid.BindingContext`).

If you run the demo below, you will see a debug message in the `Output` window indicating a property value from the view model.

```
        MyView2 objMyView2 = new MyView2();
        objMyView2.SomeProperty1 = "value1";
        objMyView2.SomeProperty2 = "value2";

        objMyView2.LaunchLocationDetailsCommand_WithParameters = new Command<object>((o2)=>
        {
            LaunchingCommands.LaunchLocationDetailsCommand_WithParameters(o2);
        });

        Grid objGrid = new Grid();
        objGrid.BindingContext = objMyView2;
        objGrid.HeightRequest = 200; 
        objGrid.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;

        TapGestureRecognizer objTapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        objTapGestureRecognizer.SetBinding(TapGestureRecognizer.CommandProperty, new Binding("LaunchLocationDetailsCommand_WithParameters"));

        Binding objBinding1 = new Binding()
        {
            Source = objGrid.BindingContext
        };
        objTapGestureRecognizer.SetBinding(TapGestureRecognizer.CommandParameterProperty, objBinding1);
        //
        objGrid.GestureRecognizers.Add(objTapGestureRecognizer);
```

Supporting classes:-

**MyView2**:-

```
public class MyView2
    : ViewModelBase
{
    public string SomeProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string SomeProperty2 { get; set; }

    public ICommand LaunchLocationDetailsCommand_WithParameters { get; set; }
}
```

**LaunchingCommands**:-

```
public static class LaunchingCommands
{
    public static void LaunchLocationDetailsCommand_WithParameters(object pobjObject)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SomeProperty1 = " + (pobjObject as MyView2).SomeProperty1);
    }
}
```

**ViewModelBase**:-

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase
    : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string pstrPropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(pstrPropertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a {Binding} with nothing inside it, it is binding to the binding context and passing that through. Hence you bind it to the default binding context of the page.

When you create a new Binding set the source.

```
var binding = new Xamarin.Forms.Binding() { Source = this.BindingContext };
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, you cannot pass in the BindingContext in the way I'm trying. How do you suggest doing this?