# Xamarin Forms How to make Global Toolbar?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms

I'd like to make Global Toolbar that is accessible in my whole application. Im using MVVM pattern..
I have tried this in my app.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
                <ContentPage x:Key="BoloTool">
                    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
                        <ToolbarItem Name="MenuItem2" Order="Secondary" Text="Moje dane" Priority="1"/>
                        <ToolbarItem Name="MenuItem4" Order="Secondary" Text="Wyloguj" Priority="1"/>
                        <ToolbarItem Name="MenuItem4" Order="Secondary" Text="Do Strony Testowej" Priority="1"/>
                        <ToolbarItem Name="MenuItem4" Order="Secondary" Text="Checkout" Priority="1"/>
                    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
                </ContentPage>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

And in one of my "Page.xaml" I did:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem BindingContext="{StaticResource BoloTool}"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

It compiles but toolbar isnt showing anything, you can hear the click sound but nothing is there and no "3 dots"

I also tried to make it that way creating a code file "x.cs" putting this:

```
public class BoloToolbar : ContentPage
{
    public BoloToolbar()
        : base()
    {
        Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem() { Text = "Help", Priority = 0, Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Secondary });
        this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem() { Text = "License", Priority = 0, Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Secondary });
        this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem() { Text = "About", Priority = 0, Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Secondary });
    }

}
```

And inheriting this in my viewmodel:

public class CartViewModel : BoloToolbar, INotifyPropertyChanged

But it doesnt work.. Im stuck, how do I do this?

Ps. Wierd that something so common as global toolbar isnt available in some tutorials..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are kind of lacking the core concepts of Xamarin.Forms. You should really dedicate some time studying them.

> And inheriting this in my viewmodel:

Inheriting your VM from the `BoloToolbar` class won't help anything. The viewmodel is *bound* to your view/page, but is different from it. You should derive your actual page from `BoloToolbar`

```
<myNameSpace:BoloToolbar x:Class="MyNamespace.MyPage" ...>
    <myNameSpace:BoloToolbar.Content>
        <!-- Your content goes here -->
    </myNameSpace:BoloToolbar.Content>
</myNameSpce:BoloToolbar>
```

Do not forget, that you have to change

```
public class MyPage : ContentPage 
{
    // ...
}
```

to

```
public class MyPage : BoloToolbar
{
    // ..
}
```

in your *MyPage.xaml.cs*.

#### Why doesn't the first option work?

In your *Application.xaml* you define a `ContentPage` in your resource dictionary, which you then try to assign to the `ToolbarItem` of another page.

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem ... /> 
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Adds *one* `ToolbarItem` to your page. Setting its `BindingContext` does not change anything about this. Furthermore, neither a `Text`, not an `Icon` is set, hence nothing is displayed.

The `ToolbarItems` is declared as an `IList<ToolbarItem>` and read-only, hence you won't be able to simply set the `ToolbarItems` via a resource. Internally it's an `ObservableCollection<ToolbarItem>` and the only way to manipulate `Page.ToolbarItems` will be by adding `ToolbarItem` objects. Hence you will be restricted to adding the items from a base class.

Comment: its working thank you a lot! How do I Bind these toolbar items to the viewmodel so I can use "Commands" ??

Comment: ok Ive got it just do                 this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("Moje Zamówienia", null, () =>
                {
                }, ToolbarItemOrder.Secondary, priority:0));

where null is the image

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35252081/2249175) explains how to set bindings from code.

Comment: one more question, do you happen to know how to "refresh" the toolbar view? Im checking if client is logged if it is Im showing him different toolbar items, but if I log in and come back to the same page it doesnt "refresh" them, like its not checking for the second time if its logged in. On different pages it works ok (once logged in and opening diff page for the first time)

Comment: @Bolo: When and how are you checking whether the user is logged in?

Comment: Im checking it in App.xaml.cs if user has property "clientid" (application.current.properties['clientid']) which I give him (the first time he logs in) then hes logged in and I save that id to my client model and access it through the application from the model. 

Its doing this everytime app is started, of course it connects to my magento server and checks if that user really exists